# How to pass apply ssrs parameters on multiple dimension attributes

Tags: reporting-services, parameter-passing, ssas, ssrs-2012, olap-cube

`@StartDate` and `@EndDate` parameters must added to the MDX query for usage in SSRS data set. `strtomember` can be used like this:

```
SELECT ( 
            strtomember(@StartDate) : strtomember(@EndDate)
        ) ON COLUMNS FROM [Cube]
```

How can I specify that sub-select must work on the `[Fact A]` and `[Fact B]` rundate? `strtomember(@StartDate)` does not specify on which attribute this sub select is going to work. Any pointers?

```
 FROM 
    ( 
    SELECT 
        ( 
            [Fact B].[Rundate].&[2015-01-02T00:00:00] : [Fact B].[Rundate].&[2015-01-15T00:00:00] 
        ) ON COLUMNS FROM 
            ( 
                SELECT 
                    ( [Fact A].[Rundate].&[2015-01-02T00:00:00] : [Fact B].[Rundate].&[2015-01-15T00:00:00] ) ON COLUMNS FROM [Cube]
            )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about your requeriments but assuming `Fact A` and `Fact B` have different `Rundate` members I think you should create a `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` for every Fact you want to filter.

Also you can have an additional parameter to select the Fact Table, once the Fact Table is selected you can populate date parameters.

If you don't have a `Time Dimension` related to Fact tables you have to populate parameters from Facts.